# The number of non-zero direct summands in a ring direct decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

> Consider a ring with identity that is the direct sum (as a ring) of non-zero subrings $A = A_1 \oplus ... \oplus A_r$. Suppose that $A$ has exactly $n$ isomorphism types of simple modules. Show that $r \le n$.

This is exercise 3.2 in *A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory*

I think I should prove it by controdiction: assume that $r \gt n$. If we can find $r$ non-isomorphic maximal left ideals $M_i, i = 1,...,r$, then we get $r (\gt n)$ non-isomorphic simple modules $A/M_i$, a contradiction. To find the maximal ideals, I wonder whether or not $A_2 \oplus ... \oplus A_r$ is a maximal left ideal. And if not, can we find a maximal ideal $N_1$ of $A_1$ so that $N_1 \oplus A_2 \oplus ... \oplus A_r$ becomes a maximal left ideal of $A$? And assume that we have found $r$ maximal left ideals how can we prove that they are non-isomorphic?

So my question is: how to properly solve this exercise? It took me hours and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found all the ingredients:

Note that for all ideals $I_i \trianglelefteq A_i$ we have that $I := I_1 \times \dotsb \times I_r$ is an ideal in $A := A_1 \times \dotsb \times A_r$.
(It can be shown that every ideal of $A$ is of this form.)
Also note that there exists an isomorphism of abelian groups
$$
        A/I
  =     (A_1 \times \dotsb \times A_r) / (I_1 \times \dotsb \times I_r)
  \cong (A_1 / I_1) \times \dotsb \times (A_r / I_r)
$$
under which the $A$-module structure of $A/I$ corresponds to
$$
    (a_1, \dotsc, a_r) \cdot ([x_1], \dotsc, [x_r])
  = ([a_1 x_1], \dotsc, [a_r x_r])
$$
for all $(a_1, \dotsc, a_r) \in A$ and $([x_1], \dotsc, [x_r]) \in (A_1 / I_1) \times \dotsb \times (A_r / I_r)$.

For every $i = 1, \dotsc, r$ there now exists a maximal (left) ideal $N_i \trianglelefteq A_i$ because $A_i$ has an identity (this is a standard application of Zorn’s Lemma, which I assume you have seen before).
The resulting ideal
$$
      M_i
  :=  A_1 \times \dotsb \times A_{i-1} \times N_i \times A_{i+1} \times \dotsb A_r
$$
is maximal in $A$:
We have that
$$
        A / M_i
  \cong 0 \times \dotsb \times 0 \times (A_i / N_i) \times 0 \times \dotsb \times 0
  \cong A_i / N_i \,,
$$
with the $A$-module structure of $A/M_i$ corresponding to
$$
    (a_1, \dotsc, a_r) \cdot [x]
  = [a_i x]
  = a_i \cdot [x]
$$
for all $(a_1, \dotsc, a_r) \in A$, $[x] \in A_i/N_i$.
It follows that $A/M_i$ is a simple $A$-module if and only if $A_i/N_i$ is simple as an $A_i$-module (because a subset $P \subseteq A_i/N_i$ is an $A_i$-submodule if and only if it is an $A$-submodule.)
But this holds because $N_i$ is a maximal submodule of $A_i$.

To see that the simple modules $A/M_1, \dotsc, A/M_r$ are pairwise non-isomorphic, consider the elements $e_1, \dotsc, e_r \in A$ which are given by $e_i = (0, \dotsc, 0, 1, 0, \dotsc, 0)$ with $1$ at the $i$-th position.
Then $e_i \cdot A/M_i = A/M_i$ but $e_i \cdot A/M_j = 0$ for all $j \neq i$.

---

The idea behind the above approach is the following:
Let $A, B$ be rings with identity.

Given an $A$-module $M_1$ and a $B$-module $M_2$, we can endow the (external) direct sum $M_1 \oplus M_2$ with the structure of an $(A \times B)$-module via
$$
      (a, b) \cdot (m_1, m_2)
  :=  (a \cdot m_1, b \cdot m_2)
$$
for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$, $(m_1, m_2) \in M_1 \oplus M_2$.

We can also decompose every $(A \times B)$-module $M$ as a(n internal) direct sum $M = M_1 \oplus M_2$ with $M_i = e_i M$ for $e_1 = (1,0)$, $e_2 = (0,1)$.
Then $M_1$ carries the structure of an $A$-module, and $M_2$ carries the structure of a $B$-module, via
$$
      a \cdot m_1
  :=  (a,0) \cdot m_1
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
      b \cdot m_2
  :=  (0,b) \cdot m_2
$$
for all $a \in A$, $b \in B$, $m_i \in M_i$.

Both of these constructions are inverse to each other (up to isomorphism), and they are compatible with submodules, quotients, homomorphisms, etc.
We can therefore think about $(A \times B)$-modules “componentwise”, one $A$-component and one $B$-component.
(We actually get an equivalence of categories
$$
          (A \times B)\mathrm{-Mod}
  \simeq  (A\mathrm{-Mod}) \times (B\mathrm{-Mod})
$$
by the above costruction.)

---

I would also like to point out that $A_i$ is not really a subring of $A$ (unless $A_j = 0$ for every $j \neq i$) because $1_{A_i} \neq 1_A$ (this is also mentioned at the beginning of section 3.6 of *A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory*, so I’m not sure why it is written this way in the exercise.)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really detailed and helpful!